# Adding OnClick Event with Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an onclick event with JavaScript.

```
$.getJSON(api , function(data) {
    //First Option found (not working)
    //document.getElementById("today_button").SetAttrribute("onclick", "window.location.replace('" + data[1] + "')");

    //Second Option found (not working either)
    document.getElementById('today_button').onclick = "window.location.replace('" + data[1] + "');";
});
```

The Variables exist, the Event is fired, the data transmitted are correct and everything except this works just fine (like altering the disabled state of exactly this button).

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a function to `onclick`, not a string:

```
document.getElementById('today_button').onclick = function(event) {
   window.location.replace(data[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning a string as a click handler? Just use a function.

```
document.getElementById('today_button').onclick = function () {
    location.replace(data[1]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you assigned string to onclick, but it needs function.

```
document.getElementById('today_button').onclick = function() {
    window.location.replace(data[1]);
}
```